# homogeneous system solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be a matrix of the order $m \times n$, $P \neq 0$. Let $Q$ be a matrix of the order $n \times m$, $Q \neq 0$. Let $P Q = 0$.

Is it necessarily true that the homogeneous system $Qx = 0$ will always have a non-trivial solution?

Comment: relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111610/if-the-product-of-two-non-zero-square-matrices-is-zero-then-both-factors-must-b

Comment: @KyleBroder that link talks about the invertibility of matrices. I need an example of two non zero matrices which product is zero AND the second one has only the trivial solution. OR a proof that there will always be a non trivial solution.