# If $AB=O$ and both $A$ and $B$ are non null matrices does that implies both $A$ and $B$ are singular or only one of them can be singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $AB=O$ and both $A$ and $B$ are non null matrices does that implies both $A$ and $B$ are singular or only one of them can be singular?

Here's what I think
If $AB=O$ and both $A$ and $B$ are non null matrices
then, $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)=0$
so either $A$ is singular or $B$ is singular .

Is this correct?

Comment: In fact, both $A$ and $B$ must be singular, assuming that "null matrix" means "zero matrix".

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You can find such problems in this site, please just look other questions before asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof that $A$ or $B$ must be singular is correct. The question is whether they both have to be singular, or it’s possible that one is full rank.

Suppose that $A$ is full rank and $AB = 0$. Then since $A$ is full rank, it’s invertible with inverse $A^{-1}$. So $B = A^{-1} 0 = 0$, making $B$ the zero matrix. Thus it is only possible for two non-zero matrices to multiply to the zero matrix when both matrices are singular.

If this is unsatisfactory, more perspectives can be found here: [If the product of two non-zero square matrices is zero, then both factors must be singular.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111610/if-the-product-of-two-non-zero-square-matrices-is-zero-then-both-factors-must-b?rq=1)